# copy-on-write: Physical addresses are distinct before writing

Tags: fork, copy-on-write

I wrote a program in C to display the correspondence between virtual addresses and physical addresses. The aim is to check whether copy-on-write is really implemented in Linux kernels. The scenario is simple. A process declares a variable, say int a; then calls fork(); After fork, both processes display the (virtual) address of variable a. Both processes are maintained alive, by using pause(), for example. In a separate program, I open the file /proc//pagemap, seek inside up to the 8-bytes entity indexed by vpn (virtual page number), and extract the physical frame number, and then the physical address of variable a. Well, it is different in the parent and the child, even though, none of the processes writes in variable a. This means that pages are duplicated in physical memory, even if the variables are not written. I did the test when a is declared in the data zone, and also in the stack (inside the main function). In both cases, even without doing any write in the variable, physical addresses are different. The only case, where the physical address of a no-written variable is the same in parent and child, is when it is declared in the heap (int *a=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)). Even in this latter case, the physical addresses are different when I use other machines. So my conclusion is that copy-(only)-on-write is not really implemented. What am I missing? My kernel is modern: Linux 3.16.1-1-ARCH x86_64.